# HTML Email Postitioning

Tags: html, css, image, html-email

I have created a HTML email and it looks awesome insider of the browser, but once I send it in an email, the tables shift and images disappear.  I am using C# to dynamically add the data to the braces.  In the CSS, there are double braces as an escape character in order for C# to add the data. All the images have linked images using absolute urls.

This is what it is supposed to look like:
http://www.calvaryccm.com/images/Email/ccmEmailDevo.html

However, it doesn't look like that when I send it.  It looks like this:

[image: broken email]

How do I fix the table shift and missing image problem?

Comment: Which email client is it not looking correct in? All of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you need to make all your styles inline for the majority of email clients. [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/) is an excellent service for this. Run it through this then give it another go.

Some other things you will probably need to do is give all `<td>`'s a width and set all images to `display:block`.

Comment: Premailer really helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Email clients generally don't support background images. Also, all styles must be inline.

See: [campaignmonitor.com/css/](http://campaignmonitor.com/css/) for a reference of what styling can and cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need to use inline styles for CSS to work in nearly all email clients, web or desktop. Take all the css rules in your `<style>` tag and put all them into `style=` attributes on each element that is to be styled.